# DB2 SqlException: SQL passed with no tokens (Error Code -4462)

Tags: java, db2, prepared-statement

Trying to use `prepareStatement` on a query from an XML file:

```
<sql><![CDATA[
  select MY_COLUMN from MY_TABLE where OTHER_COLUMN = ? 
]]>
</sql>
```

But I get this exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10234][10927][3.59.81] SQL passed with no tokens. ERRORCODE=-4462, SQLSTATE=null
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:660)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:120)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.v(jb.java:7334)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.a(jb.java:2124)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.prepareStatement(jb.java:754)
```

I read that this is because the SQL is not in a single line. Is that the cause?

I also read that in IBM Portal, you have to change `db2_zos.DbDriverType` from 2 to 4. But I think it's irrelevant to me as I don't use IBM Portal.

Nothing else useful turned up from Google. I would love to know the real cause of the error, and to find an easier fix than forcing all SQL to single line.

**Code:**

```
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();

String sSQL = queryManager.getSQL("QRY001");

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  conn = getConnection(); //a connection pool wrapper for java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(...)
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sSQL); // **** EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE

  ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(otherColumn));
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next())
  {
    arrList.add(rs.getString(1));
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new OEException(e);
} finally {
  try {
    if (rs != null) {
      rs.close();
    }
    if (ps != null) {
      ps.close();
    }
    releaseConnection(conn);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new CustomException(e);
  }
}
return arrList;
```

Comment: Show us the code that prepares and runs the statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: What do you see when you add a `System.out.println(sSQL);` after the `getSQL()` call?

Comment: were you able to successfully execute your query outside your program. I think it is because of invalid schema or not able to reach db

Comment: I'm sorry, it maybe because of a blank query because there were some XML reading problems. After fixing them, the error went away. I will have to investigate further *if* the error comes up again.

Answer (score 0):

Because the SQL execution has comments;
Please refer to the official documentation
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH14323

Also try writing it like this

```
<sql> 
  select MY_COLUMN from MY_TABLE where OTHER_COLUMN = ? 
</sql>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This was 7 years ago, and I now have zero memory of what I was trying to do back then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: why do you think this would work?

Comment: Although the problem is seven years ago, I came across this error message "ERRORCODE=-4462, SQLSTATE=null "this year. After searching for a long time, I finally came across someone asking this question, but there was no answer under the post, so I want to answer it, if other people encounter this message, it should be easy to find the error reason